# Sql Server Xml Column query performance?

Tags: sql-server, xml-column

I'm trying to query an xml column in sql server.
I've created a primary index on the column and query it using:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
where  Doc.exist('/xml/root/propertyx/text()[. = "something"]') = 1
```

In a table with 60 000 entries , this query takes some 100 ms on my local dev machine.
Is it possible to optimize this somehow to increase performance of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize for fast query times with a calculated column.  A calculated column can't use the XML functions directly, so you have to wrap them in a function:

```
go
create function dbo.GetSomethingExists(
    @Doc xml)
returns bit
with schemabinding
as begin return (
     select  @Doc.exist('/xml/root/property/text()[. = "something"]')
) end
go
create table TestTable (
    Doc xml,
    SomethingExists as dbo.GetSomethingExists(Doc) persisted
)
go
```

If you declare the function with `schemabinding`, you can create an index on SomethingExists:

```
create index IX_TestTable_SomethingExists on TestTable(SomethingExists)
```

This should make the query much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a [Secondary XML Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522562.aspx) of `Path` type might speed things up for you.